# Установка SDL2 на C#

Tags: c#, sdl2

возникли проблемы с установкой SDL2 на C#. Через nuget не устанавливается (при попытке установить пишет такой текст: "Не удалось установить пакет «sdl2.redist 2.0.5». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.8», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета."). Так-же я пробовал скачивать биндинги с гитхаба, после установки которых выводило следующее сообщение: "System.DllNotFoundException: "Не удается загрузить DLL "SDL2": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"", хотя
SDL2.d[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ll у меня уже есть.

Comment: `Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.8», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой` ?

Comment: Выясните, какие версии .NET поддерживает этот пакет. Вам же ткст ошибки явно об этом говорит, что он не поддерживает Framework 4.8.